# Early adbd on ubuntu touch device

Tags: ubuntu-touch, lightdm, upstart, adb

I need to run adbd at early boot stage (before lightdm has started) on Ubuntu touch device (Nexus 10). As far as i know, adbd is launched after login screen password is entered. In upstart scripts i have also found emergency adb, but it seems it is not working.

I have tried the following:

- I have expected emergency adb to run if lightdm is failed to launch (so i just moved lightdm binary to another place) but nothing have happened.
- Also i tried to modify emergency adb launch conditions

  start on (stopped lxc-android-config RESULT=failed) or (stopped lightdm RESULT=failed)

How can i run adbd at early boot stage?

Thank you.